# Localization solution for "I agree to the Company <clickable>Terms of Service</clickable>"

Tags: ios, swift

I have this app where next to checkbox on Sign up screen it supposed to be a sentence: *I agree to the Company Terms of Service*. And *Terms of Service* part should be clickable so user would be able to proceed to ToS screen (although user never gonna do it).

The problem is, this app will be multilingual thus all text should be localized. That's why an easy `String` + `Button` solution won't work:

ㅁ I agree to the Company **Terms of Service**

ㅁ **서비스 이용약관**에 동의합니다

In English this clickable part (**bold text**) is in the end of the sentence and in Korean it is in the beginning. In some other language it may be in the middle.

Question: how do I approach this problem? Is there some elegant way to do it? Two storyboards?

Comment: Using HTML tags: `"Key" = "I agree to the Company  <b><a href=link>Terms of Service</a></b>";` could be a solution combined with `NSAttributedString`. Also, use a `UITextView` to get the "touched" event on the link and do as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
let attributes: [NSMutableAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
                .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15),
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.init(red: 240/255, green: 230/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1)
            ]

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "tos_string".localized, attributes: attributes)
let rangeTOS = (attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "tos_string_TOS".localized)
let rangePP = (attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "tos_string_PP".localized)

attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: "https://www.example.com/resources/pages/terms.html", range: rangeTOS)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: "https://www.example.com/resources/pages/privacy.html", range: rangePP)


let linkAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
                NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.init(red: 240/255, green: 166/255, blue: 202/255, alpha: 1),
                ]

textView.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes
textView.attributedText = attributedString
textView.delegate = self
```

where `tos_string, tos_string_TOS` and `tos_string_PP` are:

```
"tos_string" = "I agree to the Company Terms of Service and Privacy Policy";
"tos_string_TOS" = "Terms of Service";
"tos_string_PP" = "Privacy Policy";
```

in `Localizable.strings`

Thank you @Larme for directions!